# Why do my huge bone broth ice cubes become tiny puddles when melted?

Tags: broth

I made some bone broth soup and froze it in ice-cube trays.

When I melt these huge ice cubes (via microwaving), they melt down to a tiny puddle of bone broth.

What gives?

Answer (score 7):

We (humans) can be pretty bad at estimating volume by eye, especially if you're putting a bunch of cubes in one bowl - they don't pack efficiently (there's a lot of air in there). You might not actually be losing that much volume.

For example, I just dumped out an ice cube tray full of cubes, and they looked like a bit over 2 cups, but once melted (and I checked by weight, I didn't lose any!), they're about one cup:

[image: ice cubes] [image: melted ice cubes]

The ice is a bit (~7%) less dense than water, but the rest of that apparent 2x reduction in volume is just the packing inefficiency. Depending on the size/shape of your cubes and the size of the vessel you're melting in, it could get exaggerated even more.

Comment: That's a nice demonstration for kosher vs table salt too. Same thing just different :)

Comment: Except salt doesn't melt, but... yeah.

Comment: Note if you freeze clean water, you get solid ice cubes. If you freeze various solutions, you often get snowy sludge on the surface, with a lot of air in it, before the remainder freezes solid and the sludge hardens to rock.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is much of a culinary question, but I'll take a stab at it.

One of two things are happening here...
1. You're overheating it. Some of the liquid has evaporated off.
2. A cube takes up more volume than it's liquid version.

I suspect a bit of both. Try reducing the power, and increasing the time. Or melt it a little bit, stir it around, melt it some more, repeat.... That'll reduce the effect of 1.

Comment: A simple way to see if (1) is really a problem is to simply let a cube melt in the fridge.

Comment: @Batman I wouldn't trust such an experiment. The fridge has a very dry air and the ice cube will melt very slowly there. You'll get extra evaporation in the fridge even though there is not much heat. Fridges dry stuff out.

Comment: Good point. you could just put the cube in a plastic bag o rsomething to avoid this.